# R - apply() function what is the structure of output data?

Tags: r, output, sequence, apply

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
chrom value Astart     Aend  Bstart    Bend
 chr1     0      0 54519752   17408   17431
 chr1     0      0 54519752   17368   17391
 chr1     0      0 54519752  567761  567783
 chr1     0      0 54519752 1231524 1231545
 chr1     0      0 54519752 1231489 1231509
 chr1     0      0 54519752 1247918 1247941
```

The following code is supposed to give me the sequences between Bstart and Bend-1 for each row,

```
s <- unlist(apply(df, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) seq(x[5], as.numeric(x[6])-1)))
```

it seems correct but I don't understand the output:

```
> head(s,28)
   11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19   110   111   112   113   114
17408 17409 17410 17411 17412 17413 17414 17415 17416 17417 17418 17419 17420 17421
  115   116   117   118   119   120   121   122   123    21    22    23    24    25
17422 17423 17424 17425 17426 17427 17428 17429 17430 17368 17369 17370 17371 17372
```

Is this a dataframe? A list of integers? What does the upper line mean and where does it come from? Why does it start at 11? And why does it skip from 19 to 110 and then back to 21? This makes no sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is simpler with `mapply`:

```
unlist(mapply(seq, df$Bstart, df$Bend - 1))
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! So the upper line which I was trying to figure out is actually completely irrelevant? that's a relief